# Can lldb inspect what has been written to a file, or the data in an IPC mechanism it has generated/used, at a breakpoint?

Tags: lldb

Say with this simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

After stepping `printf("Hello World!\n”);` perhaps there’s a command to print that “Hellow World!\n” has been written to STDOUT.

And after `return 0` perhaps there’s a command to see the exit codes generated and it will show 0.

Are there such commands or similar in lldb?

Answer (score 0):

LLDB prints the exit status when a process exits:

```
(lldb) run
Process 76186 launched: '/tmp/a.out' (x86_64)
Process 76186 exited with status = 10 (0x0000000a)
```

and you can also access it with the SB API's:

```
(lldb) script lldb.process.GetExitStatus()
10
```

lldb doesn't have any special knowledge about all the ways a program might read or write data to a pipe, file handle, pty, etc...  It also doesn't know how to interpose on file handles and tee-off the output.  There's no particular reason it couldn't, but nobody has added that to date.

So you would have to build this yourself.  If you know the API your code is using to read and write, you could use breakpoints to observe that - though that might get slow if you are observing a program that reads and writes a lot.